# Função Mail() php, dados de pedido

Tags: php, email

Fiz um projeto onde tenho uma página de `Pedidos.php` que o *action* vai para esse código abaixo `action="anexa.php"`.

Tudo funciona corretamente com o envio para o e-mail, mas gostaria de, em uma página de "Meus pedidos", mostrar uma numeração do pedido, material e quantidade, para a pessoa saber o pedido que fez.

*anexa.php*

```
    <?php
    include("Mail.php");
    include("Mail/mime.php");

    $up = 0;

    $nome       = $_POST['nome'];
    $telefone   = $_POST['telefone'];
    $email      = $_POST['email'];
    $material   = $_POST['material'];
    $cor        = $_POST['cor'];
    $quantidade = $_POST['quantidade'];
    $acabamento = $_POST['acabamento'];
    $formato    = $_POST['formato'];
    $altura     = $_POST['altura'];
    $largura    = $_POST['largura'];
    $papel      = $_POST['papel'];
    $gramatura  = $_POST['gramatura'];
    $descricao  = $_POST['descricao'];

    $recipients = 'contato@conexaografica.com.br';

    $headers = array(
        'From' => 'contato@conexaografica.com.br',
        'To' => $recipients,
        'Subject' => "Pedido de $email"
    );

    $crlf = "\r\n";
    $text = "

    Um novo pedido foi realizado por: $nome

                   DETALHES DO PEDIDO:</br></br>

            Telefone: $telefone</br>
            Email: $email</br>
      ____________________________________</br></br>

            Material: $material</br>
            Acabamento: $acabamento</br>
            Formato: $formato</br>
            Tamanho = $altura x $largura</br>
            Cor: $cor</br>
            Papel : $papel</br>
            Gramatura: $gramatura</br>
            Quantidade: $quantidade</br></br>

            Descricoes: $descricao";
    $html = "$text";

    $mime = new Mail_mime($crlf);

    $mime->setHTMLBody($html);

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['anexo']['name']); $i++) {

        if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['anexo']['tmp_name'][$i])) {
            $caminho[$i] = "/home/conexaografica/www/areaderevendedor/tmp/" . $_FILES['anexo']['name'][$i];

            if (copy($_FILES['anexo']['tmp_name'][$i], $caminho[$i])) {
                $mime->addAttachment($caminho[$i]);
                unlink($caminho[$i]);
                echo "Seu arquivo foi anexado!<br>";
            }
        } else {
            echo "O arquivo não foi transferido!";
            echo "Caminho ou nome de arquivo Inválido";
        }
    }
    $body    = $mime->get();
    $headers = $mime->headers($headers);

    $params = array(
        'auth' => true,
        'host' => 'smtp.conexaografica.com.br',
        'username' => 'contato=conexaografica.com.br',
        'password' => 'conexaografica'
    );

    $mail_object = Mail::factory('smtp', $params);
    $result      = $mail_object->send($recipients, $headers, $body);
    if (PEAR::IsError($result)) {
        echo "Algo deu errado... (" . $result->getMessage() . ")";
    } else {
        echo "Seu pedido foi realizado com sucesso.";

    }
?>
```

Comment: Você resolve isso incluindo mais script (HTML e PHP) ao final deste código. Porém neste trecho você não passa o número do pedido.

Comment: Eu não entendo muito sobre PHP... poderia me ajudar nessa questão?

Answer (score 0):

Tente o seguinte código no lugar de anexa.php

Compare os dois e verá que coloquei o html junto do php, de forma que depois de enviar a mensagem ele mostra uma página com os dados enviados ou a mensagem de erro.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><!-- copie o head de Pedidos.php, se houver --></head>
<body>
<?php // neste trecho, você deveria salvar os dados em um banco de dados
      // e assim obter um número de pedido. Daí poderá usar os dados mais
      // tarde, por exemplo, numa página de consulta de pedidos
?>

<?php
    include("Mail.php");
    include("Mail/mime.php");

    $up = 0;

    $nome       = $_POST['nome'];
    $telefone   = $_POST['telefone'];
    $email      = $_POST['email'];
    $material   = $_POST['material'];
    $cor        = $_POST['cor'];
    $quantidade = $_POST['quantidade'];
    $acabamento = $_POST['acabamento'];
    $formato    = $_POST['formato'];
    $altura     = $_POST['altura'];
    $largura    = $_POST['largura'];
    $papel      = $_POST['papel'];
    $gramatura  = $_POST['gramatura'];
    $descricao  = $_POST['descricao'];

    $recipients = 'contato@conexaografica.com.br';

    $headers = array(
        'From' => 'contato@conexaografica.com.br',
        'To' => $recipients,
        'Subject' => "Pedido de $email"
    );

    $crlf = "\r\n";
    $text = "

    Um novo pedido foi realizado por: $nome

                   DETALHES DO PEDIDO:</br></br>

            Telefone: $telefone</br>
            Email: $email</br>
      ____________________________________</br></br>

            Material: $material</br>
            Acabamento: $acabamento</br>
            Formato: $formato</br>
            Tamanho = $altura x $largura</br>
            Cor: $cor</br>
            Papel : $papel</br>
            Gramatura: $gramatura</br>
            Quantidade: $quantidade</br></br>

            Descricoes: $descricao";
    $html = "$text";

    $mime = new Mail_mime($crlf);

    $mime->setHTMLBody($html);

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['anexo']['name']); $i++) {

        if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['anexo']['tmp_name'][$i])) {
            $caminho[$i] = "/home/conexaografica/www/areaderevendedor/tmp/" . $_FILES['anexo']['name'][$i];

            if (copy($_FILES['anexo']['tmp_name'][$i], $caminho[$i])) {
                $mime->addAttachment($caminho[$i]);
                unlink($caminho[$i]);
                echo "Seu arquivo foi anexado!<br>";
            }
        } else {
            echo "O arquivo não foi transferido!";
            echo "Caminho ou nome de arquivo Inválido";
        }
    }
    $body    = $mime->get();
    $headers = $mime->headers($headers);

    $params = array(
        'auth' => true,
        'host' => 'smtp.conexaografica.com.br',
        'username' => 'contato=conexaografica.com.br',
        'password' => 'conexaografica'
    );

    $mail_object = Mail::factory('smtp', $params);
    $result      = $mail_object->send($recipients, $headers, $body);
    if (PEAR::IsError($result)) {
        echo "Algo deu errado... (" . $result->getMessage() . ")";
    } else {            
        echo("<P>$nome, Seu pedido foi realizado com sucesso.</P>". 
        "<P align="center">DETALHES DO PEDIDO:</P>".
        "<P>Telefone: $telefone <br>".
        "Email: $email <br>".
        "____________________________________</P>".
        "<P>Material: $material <br>".
        "Acabamento: $acabamento <br>".
        "Formato: $formato <br>".
        "Tamanho = $altura x $largura <br>".
        "Cor: $cor <br>".
        "Papel : $papel <br>".
        "Gramatura: $gramatura <br>".
        "Quantidade: $quantidade</P>";          
    }
?>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Além da página de sucesso do envio do pedido, esses dados podem ser printado em outra? Desculpe  demora, é que estive ausente!

Comment: Se entendi o fluxo, o usuário preenche um form. e ao clicar no botão "ok", uma mensagem de email é enviada com os eventuais anexos. Eu só te mostrei como exibir os dados enviados na tela de sucesso. Pra levar estes dados pra outra página, você precisa salvar os dados.

Comment: eu não coloquei pra ir pro banco de dados, porque essa parte de pedido, tem muitas opções dentro de alguns select.

Comment: não entendo muito, não sei se desse jeito com a função mail, tem como continuar só que da mesma forma ir mandando pro banco

Comment: A logica do programa deve ser gravar os dados antes de fazer outra coisa com eles. O HTML não tem estado, isto é, não guarda nenhuma informação automaticamente, você deve salvar especificamente. Ou seja, depois de clicar no botão <ok>,  o script deve salvar os dados num banco de dados que por sua vez vai gerar um numero de registro (ID) que você pode usar como numero do pedido, se quiser. Somente então, você deve enviar o email e mandar os dados para a tela de "sucesso". Coloquei um comentário (//) no código, onde deveria ocorrer a gravação dos dados.

Comment: Obrigado pela atenção meu amigo, vou  fazer isso e te retorno.

Comment: Bom meu amigo, Os dados não estão sendo enviados para o banco, e não tem mensagem de erro aparecendo.

Comment: Desculpe amigo, agora consegui, está tudo correto, enviando pro banco, e pro email, e coloquei pra gerar um numero aleatorio, que é printado na tela, enviado pro email e enviado pro banco, o mesmo numero. agora a minha duvida é de como montar a area de meus pedidos com o pedido da pessoa especifica, não pode correr o risco de vir pedido de outra pessoa? como está indo tudo pro mesmo banco. não sei exatamente como devo fazer, como disse eu não entendo muito.

Comment: @ErickFaria, acho que a ideia deste fórum é manter o foco. As vezes, a resposta não é exatamente o que a gente queria, mas abre o caminho para encontrar a solução, e também abre novos questionamentos. Acho que este é um caso assim. Você aprendeu que não basta enviar o email, tem todo um fluxo a seguir. Agora, pesquisa um pouco sobre isso, tenta novos códigos e traga novas perguntas. Ou então, pegue esta pergunta que você fez acima e gere uma nova.